# Unable to login to facebook due to Network Exception

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, htc-desire

In **HTC m7** . When I `login` to `facebook` . It shows me an error

Please check your network connection or try again later.

(`HttpNetworkException: AsynSocketException:` connect failed, type = Socket not open errn= 101(**Network is unreachable**)

Comment: What kind of network are you on: Wi-Fi or mobile data? Do other internet apps work on this network? Can you get to facebook.com in your web browser on this network?

Comment: Yes everything else is working fine. Google play let me install any app and I am able to open google chrome and can serf it